# This program i am creating for Fibonacci but it return none.Kindly solve this problem

Tags: python

```
def fibonacci(n):
    for i in range(n,1):
        fab=0
        if(i>1):
            fab=fab+i
            i=i-1
            return fab

        elif i==0:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1



n1 = int(input("enter the nth term:  "))
n2=fibonacci(n1)
print(n2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way your code can return none is if you enter an invalid [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), where the start value is greater than or equal to the stop value (1)

you probably just need `range(n)` instead of `range(n, 1)`

Comment: I certainly agree that this is why the function is returning None. But it may also be worthwhile to discuss why, even after fixing that problem, `fibonacci(6)` returns 0, rather than the sixth fibonacci number, 8.

Comment: @Kevin - Perhaps but that isn't the question being asked, "but it return none.Kindly solve this problem" - If the op has other issues they should raise them as another question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    return 0 if n == 1 else (1 if n == 2 else (fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2) if n > 0 else None))


print(fibonacci(12))
```

Answer (score 0):

`range(n,1)` creates a range starting with n, incrementing in steps of 1 and stopping when n is larger or equal to 1. So, in case n is negative or zero, your loop will be executed. But in case n is 1 or larger, the loop will never be executed and the function just returns None.

If you would like a range going from n downwards to 1, you can use `range(n,1,-1)` where -1 is the step value.  Note that when stepping down, the last number is included `range(5,1,-1)` is `[5,4,3,2,1]` while when stepping upwards `range(1,5)` is `[1,2,3,4]` the last element is not included. `range(n)` with only one parameter also exists. It is equivalent to `range(0, n)` and goes from `0` till `n-1`, which means the loop would be executed exactly `n` times.

Also note that you write `return` in every clause of the `if` statement. That makes that your function returns its value and interrupts the `for` loop.

Further, note that you set `fab=0` at the start of your `for` loop. This makes that it is set again and again to 0 each time you do a pass of the loop. Therefore, it is better to put `fab=0` just before the start of the loop.

As others have mentioned, even with these changes, your function will not calculate the Fibonacci numbers. A recursive function is a simple though inefficient solution. Some fancy playing with two variables can calculate Fibonacci in a `for` loop. Another interesting approach is memorization or caching as demonstrated by @Ganathor.

Here is a solution that without recursion and without caching. Note that Fibonacci is a very special case where this works. Recursion and caching are very useful tools for more real world problems.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = a + b, a  # note that a and b get new values simultaneously
    return a

print (fibonacci(100000))
```

And if you want a really, really fast and fancy code:

```
def fibonacci_fast(n):
    a = 1
    b = 0
    p = 0
    q = 1
    while n > 0 :
        if n % 2 == 0 :
             p, q = p*p + q*q, 2*p*q + q*q
             n = n // 2
        else:
             a, b = b*q + a*q + a*p, b*p + a*q
             n = n - 1
    return b

print (fibonacci_fast(1000000))
```

Note that this relies on some special properties of the Fibonacci sequence. It also gets slow for Python to do calculations with really large numbers. The millionth Fibonacci number has more than 200,000 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use recursion for for nth Fibonacci number:

ex:

```
def Fibonacci(n): 
    if n==1: 
        return 0
    elif n==2: 
        return 1
    else: 
        return Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2)
print(Fibonacci(9))
# output:21
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not plan to use large numbers, you can use the easy and simple typical recursive way of programming this function, although it may be slow for big numbers (>25 is noticeable), so take it into account.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n<=0:
        return 0
    if n==1:
        return 1
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
```

You can also add a cache for the numbers you already stepped in, in order to make it run much faster. It will consume a very small amount of extra memory but it allows you to calculate larger numbers instantaneously (you can test it with fibonacci(1000), which is almost the last number you can calculate due to recursion limitation)

```
cache_fib = {}
def fibonacci(n):
    if n<=0:
        return 0
    if n==1:
        return 1
    if n in cache_fib.keys():
        return cache_fib[n]

    result = fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
    cache_fib[n] = result
    return result
```

In case you really need big numbers, you can do this trick to allow more recursion levels:

```
cache_fib = {1:1}
def fibonacci(n):
    if n<=0:
        return 0
    if n in cache_fib.keys():
        return cache_fib[n]

    max_cached = max(cache_fib.keys())
    if n-max_cached>500:
        print("max_cached:", max_cached)
        fibonacci(max_cached+500)

    result = fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
    cache_fib[n] = result
    return result
```